# Check out a project from a Bitbucket GIT repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created a project in Eclipse and checked it into a Bitbucket repository. Now I am trying to check it out from other computers. The only option that I seem to have from Eclipse is to check out the whole repository. I only need to check out the new project on other computers instead of the whole repository.

I have tried a pull in order to get the change in the repository but I get a message saying that everything is up to date.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You might provide some more detail about what you have that you are calling repository and project, some commands and outputs.

Comment: A repository on Bitbucket is a place holder for projects.

Comment: In Eclipse a project can be a Java project, a web project, a maven project and so on. Note that Bitbucket is based on GIT technology.

Comment: You clone a repository, not a part of the repository. You can use a shallow clone to avoid bringing in the whole history and a sparse checkout to only check out part of the folders in a repository, but in practice the latter is a sign of bad repository design. You shouldn't have 1 repository with N projects, you should have 1 repository per project.

Comment: Lasse, with SVN I can have a repository with multiple projects and this structure works fine. That's why I have used the same design in GIT. For sure having 1 project per repository will work, but I was hoping to make my design work similarly in GIT but as you pointed out GIT seems to provide 1 project per repository. Please correct me if I got this wrong.